# Why to include all HTLML code inside php?

Tags: php, html

My question relates to the 'why' part of the question.

I was recently working on a website for a client with another developer and the code was in standard html with separate css files. Then the client changed their requirements to include things like dynamic buttons, subscribe to newsletter things, maybe these require php. But the developer I was working with changed all the html files to php files.

Now I can see the code and make changes like I would to normal html, but php files dont seem to open in a browser so I cant check changes either.

The main question is, why would someone convert .html to .php?

Comment: *"why would someone convert .html to .php?"* To be able to execute php code on the pages

Comment: doesnt php code work like js inside html?

Comment: Nope, it's executed on server side

Comment: I **strongly** suggest you to follow some php tutorials

Comment: probably best to read what is PHP first, to summarize- php is a server side language which compile php syntax to a readable text, for you to open it in the browser, you basically need a localhost and serve the php files

Comment: You can read this comparison with explanation on difference and how they play together : https://www.bitdegree.org/tutorials/php-vs-html/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is even a single line of PHP code in whole file then that file has to be renamed .php so that PHP part of it is executed. Thus when your client added features which required PHP to be used then the extension had to be made .php instead of .html otherwise the PHP code would not execute the underlying logic.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the servers (Apache, Nginx) looks for **.php** extensions in a file to run PHP scripts. They treat **.html** as static documents.

Hence, you need to convert to PHP extensions from HTML